# Dummy indice integration tensors?

Tags: integration, tensors

I'm trying to understand why integrating
\begin{align}
dw =c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{kl}\,d\epsilon_{ij},
\end{align}
gives
\begin{align}
w =\frac{1}{2}c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{kl}\epsilon_{ij}, \tag{1}
\end{align}
given that the constants have the properties $$c_{ijkl}=c_{klij}=c_{lkij}=c_{klji}=c_{jikl}=c_{jilk}.$$

If the indices are $i,j,k,l=1,2$ then there are terms like
$$
c_{1111}\epsilon_{11}\,d\epsilon_{11}, \ \ \ c_{2222}\epsilon_{22}\,d\epsilon_{22},\ \ \ \ 4\times c_{1212}\epsilon_{12}\,d\epsilon_{12},
$$
which seem to agree with (1). However, the terms (multiples due to terms being the same through the symmetries of $c_{ijkl}$)
$$
4\times c_{1222}\epsilon_{22}\,d\epsilon_{12},\ \ \ 4\times c_{1112}\epsilon_{12}\,d\epsilon_{11}, \ \ \ 2\times c_{1122}\epsilon_{22}\,d\epsilon_{11},
$$
would not seem to give the factor of 1/2 in (1) when integrated (integrating constants).

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the product rule $$d(\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl})=d\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}+\epsilon_{ij}d\epsilon_{kl}$$
contracting with $c_{ijkl}$
$$c_{ijkl}d(\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl})=c_{ijkl}d\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}+c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}d\epsilon_{kl}$$
Then because of the symmetry $c_{ijkl}=c_{klij}$ the two terms in the RHS are equal, so that
$$c_{ijkl}d(\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl})=2c_{ijkl}d\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}$$
$$\implies c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}d\epsilon_{kl}=\frac{1}{2}d(c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl})$$
Where $c_{ijkl}$ can get inside $d$ because it is constant.
Integrate both sides to get the desired result.

Comment: Of course!! I was overcomplicating things. Appreciated!

Comment: @stressed1767 A pleasure. :) Sorry for the delay.